# Как правильно: Концерт пройдет "на палубе теплоходов" или "на палубах теплоходов"

Tags: множественное-число

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно:  Концерт пройдет "на палубе теплоходов" или "на палубах теплоходов"

Нужно ли мн.ч. у "палубы", если теплоходы уже во множественном?

Comment: не понятно как это все будет выглядеть и о чем это. Или концерт пройдет на палубе теплохода или концерты пройдут на палубах теплоходов. Ну или концерт пройдет на палубах теплохода, если у него несколько палуб.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю так: надо хорошо представлять, о чем идет речь.

*(1) Концерт пройдет **на палубах** теплоходов (а не где-то на берегу).*

*(2) Концерт пройдет **на палубе** теплоходов (а не в концертом зале этих теплоходов).*

Comment: (1) Концерт пройдет на палубах теплоходов (а не в концертных залах этих теплоходов). (2) Концерт пройдет на палубе теплоходов (а не где-то на берегу).

Comment: Может быть, и так...   А если записать решение в общем виде, то как будет? Что-то вроде: Единственное число пишем, если...

Comment: Ну множественное во всех контекстах может заменять единственное, обратное почти всегда верно, кроме экзотических случаев типа "На палубу кораблей вышло по капитану."

Comment: Я думаю, что нужно указывать обоснование для выбора числа по смыслу, причем желательно подвести вывод под правило (у Розенталя, например).

Comment: Ну да, у Розенталя принято различать "два человека вошли в бар" и "два человека вошло в бар", но я бы не стал.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно и так и так

> 11. И. А. Гончаров. Фрегат «Паллада» (1855)
>
> В океане, в мгновенных встречах, тот же образ виден был **на палубе
> кораблей**, насвистывающий сквозь зубы: «Rule, Britannia, upon the sea».

Ну и еще несколько аналогичных примеров с другими словами

> А через секунду в глазах ее блеснул огонек, и кровь залила обе щеки, когда ее взгляд приметил нервную дрожь **на лице Морозовых**
>
> отражаются **на лице подсудимых**
>
> Конечно, многим свойственно бояться родов, но подобной горестной маски
> **на лице беременных** мне что-то видеть не приходилось.
>
> волосы **на голове евнухов** растут прекрасно.
>
> Тот самый кол, который приходится тесать **на голове тупиц** второе столетие.

Comment: причем тут *образ*, *встречал образ* и пройдет концерт? совершенно несовместимые вещи

Comment: Образ был виден (где?) на палубе кораблей. Концерт пройдет (где?) на палубе кораблей

Comment: Образ не концерт, образ - внутренняя вещь, а концерт внешнее действие. Образ один и *тот же* - вне модальности, концерт - привязан к месту, времени и тд.

Comment: Концерт привязан к времени и месту (где? - на каждой из палуб). Лицезрение образа привязано к времени и месту (где? на каждой из палуб). Давайте что-нибудь попроще: "Концерт звучал на каждой площади города" - нормальная фраза? Или еще проще: "Концерт звучал на каждом квадратном метре города"

Comment: Все примеры - образные выражения, фразеологизмы почти или именно они, переносные значения. Кроме разве что волос на голове, где речь именно про голову, что на голове растут волосы у евнухов. На палубе кораблей можно проводить концерты - общие вещи какие-то, неконкретные

Comment: "Палуба кораблей побелела." - где тут образность выражения? "концерт звучал (был слышен) на каждой площади города" - а тут где образность?

Comment: Так можно много примеров приводить, толку будет мало, все зависит от того, что нужно сказать. Тут палуба какого-то класса кораблей, не конкретная палуба, почему-то побелела. А в примере речь идет о концерте который "пройдет" - конкретный концерт, не ясно когда пройдет правда. Может как волосы - концерты пройдут на палубе кораблей, возможно, но не волос растет не голове евнухов - бредово звучит.

Comment: "Концерт пройдет на каждом квадратном метре поля" - конкретный концерт, на метре какого-то класса (поля)

Comment: Прекрасно, а о чем это сообщение? Можете смысл расшифровать? Может еще взвесите концерт? Нет, ну можно сказать, что заяц живет в норе и предпочитает разнотравье на лугах, - но это уже по стилистике, не повествовательный текст. Потому что заяц - не конкретный заяц, а вид животного - общее понятие. Вот и у вас концерт будет общим понятием, если вы его будете мерить метрами и палубами.

Comment: Смысл в том, что конкретный концерт будет везде на данном поле. Не в какой-то части поля, а прямо везде.

Comment: Концерт не дом, как он может проходить на каждом метре, что за бред? Концертная площадка - может стоять, но как концерт будет проходить на каждом метре? Как будто у концерта есть физические параметры, а их нет.

Comment: "Концерт проходит сразу на нескольких сценах комплекса" - нормальное выражение? "Концерт проходит по всему периметру футбольного поля" - нормальное?

Comment: не нормально, криво.

Comment: "Концерт проходит сразу на нескольких сценах комплекса", ну тут уж извиняйте, 100% нормальное предложение. А от него потихонечку раскручиваемся до каждой палубы кораблей

Comment: Да? и что это значит? как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: Представляю как: "Концертное мероприятие проходит сразу на нескольких сценах комплекса"

Comment: Одновременно?ххх